# Use of か in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> STARTボタンを押す**か**「メニュー」をタッチで開けてみろ！

Why is か used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just *or*.

Presumably you are holding a game pad and seeing a screen. It says you press START or touch the menu on the screen.